# How to embed html when used in innerText function?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

There is some site I have to work with, which takes a string and inserts it using innerText function. I want to insert the string
`<font color='red'>*</font>` so it becomes red. The problem is that since it's innerText, this exact string shows up on the page. I want the html part of the string to get evaluated in html code.

Is there some trick I can do to change the string so that when it gets inserted using innerText, it will still become red?

**Note:** I *cannot* use `innerHTML` or change the original code.

Thanks.

Comment: No, there is no workaround.

Comment: Please consider not using `<font>` tags; it's 2013.

Comment: This is the difference between innerText and innerHTML: text is treated literally, HTML is parsed as HTML. There's no getting around it.

Answer (score 2):

Try using innerHTML instead of innerText.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.innerHTML

Comment: I don't think that he has access to the foreign site.

Comment: I cannot change the function. I can only modify the string I give the application.